# “Absolutely equal” linear functionals and collinearity

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb C$ and let $X^*$ denote its dual (*i.e.*, the space of all continuous linear complex-valued functions over $X$). Suppose that $f,g\in X^*$ satisfy the property that $|f(x)|=|g(x)|$ for all $x\in X$. Does it necessarily follow that $f$ and $g$ are collinear in the sense that there exists some $c\in\mathbb C$ such that $f(x)=cg(x)$ for any $x\in X$? Or does there exist a nice counterexample?

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|f(x)|=|g(x)|$ for all $x$ then $\ker f=\ker g$. If $f\neq 0$ there is a $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=1$. Suppose $g(x)=\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|\alpha|=1$. Then $g=\alpha f$.

Comment: How does it follows that the ratio of $g(y)$ to $f(y)$ is the same at all $y\in X$ as at $y=x$?

Comment: Diestel, J. Sequences and series in Banach spaces.
Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 92. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1984. p 10. Lemma: Let $E$ be a linear space and $f,g_1,\ldots,g_n$ be linear functionals on $E$ such that $\cap_{i=1}^n \ker g_i \subset \ker f $. Then $f$ is a linear combination of the $g_i$'s. Apply this lemma.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much.

Comment: Suppose $f(y)=c\in\mathbb{C}$. Then $f(y)=cf(x)=f(cx)$ so $f(y-cx)=0$. Thus $y-cx\in\ker f=\ker g$. From here we deduce $g(y)=cg(x)=c\alpha$ that means the ratio of $g(y)$ to $f(y)$ is the same.